# Who is the subject of Aにはaction?

Tags: particles

Here's an example.

メイドにはびびった

Who was scared, the speaker, or the maid?

Comment: It depends on the verb.
The question is just a translation request, I vote for closing.

Comment: I don't think it's just a translation request, because I made it general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is context-dependent. It *could* be the speaker that was frightened, but it could just as easily be the most recent subject (e.g. person) being discussed prior to this sentence. Without more context, it's really impossible to say for certain. In any case, though, *someone* or *something* was frightened *by* the maid.